# Navbar Search button in bootstrap is not working properly

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

As the you seen the search button is below and I want to slide the whole search section to right most corner and next to each other
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJD2X.png

```html
    <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
          <button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please post reproducible code, see how to post reproducible code here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Code.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `input-group` class in bootstrap to make this work.

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
           <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                      placeholder="Search">
                   <button class="btn btn-outline-success" 
                     type="button" 
                     id="addon-btn">
                     Button
                   </button>
          </div>
</form>
```

Please refer to the [documentation here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/) for more advanced usage.

Answer (score 1):

ADD class to this one like this : `<input className="form-control mr-sm-2 inlineb" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>`

and in css add This : .inlineb { display : inline-block}